# To test the convergence of series 2

Tags: sequences-and-series

To test the convergence of series 2

$\displaystyle \frac{a+x}{1!}+\frac{(a+2x)^2}{2!}\frac{(a+3x)^3}{3!}+...\infty$

My Attempt:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{u_n}{u_{n+1}} & = \frac{(a+nx)^n}{n!}\frac{(n+1)!}{(a+(n+1)x)^{n+1}} \\
 & = \frac{(a+nx)^n}{1}\frac{n+1}{(a+nx+x)^{n+1}} \\ 
 & = \frac{(x+a/n)^n}{1}\frac{1+1/n}{(x+a/n+x/n)^{n+1}}  \\
 & = \frac{x^n(1+a/nx)^n}{1}\frac{1+1/n}{x^{n+1}(1+a/nx+1/n)^{n+1}}  \\ 
 & = \frac{(1+a/nx)^n}{1}\frac{1+1/n}{(1+a/nx+1/n)^{n+1}}\frac{1}{x} \\
 & = ??
\end{align}$$

I see an "e" in the limit $n\to \infty$ here, but can't quite get "there". Any hints?

Comment: If you know Stirling's formula, the root test is nicer, IMO.

Comment: Wait! Did you learn anything from the answer to your previous question? Did you use it to complete the problem over there? Or are you just trying to outrun the wind...

Comment: I did solve the first series in the previous question..but there are a lot of problems that I get stuck somewhere or the other..

Comment: Nice to know. Then why do you fail to acknowledge the fact on the other page? (Unrelated: Please use @.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{u_n}{u_{n+1}}
 & = lim_{n \to \infty} (1+a/nx)^n\frac{1+1/n}{(1+a/nx+1/n)^{n+1}}\frac{1}{x} \\
 & =lim_{n \to \infty} (1+a/nx)^n\frac{1}{ lim_{n \to \infty}(1+(a+x)/nx)^n}\frac{1}{x}\\ 
&= e^{a/x} \dfrac{1}{xe^{a+x/x}}\\ &=\dfrac{e^{-1}}{x}\end{align}$$
Therefore your series is convergent for all $e^{-1}>|x|.$ But I don't have any idea about how to find the sum.

Answer (score 0):

Follow Did's advice, you should get something like 
$$
a^{\frac{1}{n}}_n = \frac{a+nx}{(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}} \sim \frac{e(a+nx)}{n} (2 \pi n)^{-\frac{1}{2n}}
$$
The last term converges to 1, so the series converges for $x<e^{-1}$